# Tensoflow Estimator: how to use tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I would like to know if it is possible to use the function *[tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/convert_variables_to_constants)* (in order to store the frozen version of the graph) in a train/evaluation loop, while I'm using a custom estimators. For example:

```py
best_validation_accuracy = -1
for _ in range(steps // how_often_validation):

    # Train the model
    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=how_often_validation)

    # Evaluate the model
    validation_accuracy = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)

    # Save best model
    if validation_accuracy["accuracy"] > best_validation_accuracy:
        best_validation_accuracy = validation_accuracy["accuracy"]
        # Save best model perfomances
        # I WANT TO USE  tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the function `tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`, you need the graph and the session of your model.

After going through the [TensorFlow code defining the estimators](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py), it appears that:

- This code is deprecated,
- The graph is created on the fly and not easily accessible (at least, I was not able to retrieve it).

Thus, we will have to use the good old method.

When you call `estimator.train`, checkpoints of your model are being saved in a specified directory (`estimator.model_dir`). You can use those files to access the graph and session and freeze the variables as follow:

#### 1. Load meta graph

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/path/to/meta')
```

#### 2. Load weights

```
sess = tf.Session
saver.restore(sess, '/path/to/weights')
```

#### 3. Freeze variables

```
tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess,
                                             sess.graph.as_graph_def(),
                                             ['output'])
```